# a specific plinq query

Tags: c#, dictionary, plinq

i want to select one id that have max value in a C# `dictionary<int, double>`

for example

initial dictionary

```
 1   0.8   
 2   0.78   
 3   0.9   
 4   0.87
```

after select

```
 3   0.9
```

my current code

```
dic.AsParallel().Max(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: And what is your question / problem?

Comment: Why have you decided you want to use PLINQ for this specific query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic.AsParallel().First(y => y.Value == dic.Select(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Max())).Key
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a `MaxBy` construct. That doesn't exist in normal LINQ to Objects, although I have one in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com), so you'd write:

```
var result = dictionary.MaxBy(pair => pair.Value);
```

However, that won't be parallelized in the way that you'd want. You could at least *try* using [this overload of `ParallelEnumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383937.aspx) having created your own comparable type containing the relevant values:

```
public class ComparablePair : IComparable<ComparablePair>
{
    // Have key and value, then implement IComparable<T> by
    // comparing values
}
```

Then use:

```
var result = dictionary.AsParallel()
                       .Max(pair => new ComparablePair(pair));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about OrderBy(x => x.Value).First() ?